# Gradient background without images

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can I create a gradient background for my form and text without using any images and how can I add multiple images in same form background in VB.NET?

Comment: I want to use in windows form VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this post

http://www.getdotnetcode.com/nexDotNet/030005H2GradientBg4WinFormVB/H2GradientBg4WinFormVB.htm

Thank you.